# How can I access elements of an iframe with a URL on the same subdomain?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, iframe, web-scraping

I have an iframe on a subdomain foo.mysite.com. I want to access the contents of a table within the iframe, which has a URL on bar.mysite.com. I can alter foo.mysite.com, but not bar.mysite.com. Hence, I just set `document.domain` on foo.mysite.com to bar.mysite.com. However, Chrome Developer Tools is still complaining

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

I suspect that the Same Origin Policy requires both sites to explicitly set the same `document.origin` value. Is there any way I could temporarily disable XSS checking on Chrome to access the iframe's elements? I just want to scrape some data from a table in the iframed page using Javascript.

Comment: Where's the code that brings about that error?

Comment: Here is a concrete example of what I am trying to do with a page created on Dropbox. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/Misc/subDomainFrameAccess/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's due to Same Origin Policy. You can disable it for you, but not for others. You must add this argument to chrome shortcut :

```
--disable-web-security
```

Comment: Thank you, what are Chrome shortcuts? I have been Googling around, but have just gotten links to keyboard shortcuts :)

Comment: For a mac : $ open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
For a PC : cmd > go to chrome.exe directory, type "chrome.exe --disable-web-security"
For a PC (other solution) : go to chrome shortcut (on desktop for example) >right click > properties > add " --disable-web-security" to the link

Comment: Thanks! I have a mac. For some reason, accessing the iframe on this page isn't quite working even with the Chrome shortcut: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/Misc/subDomainFrameAccess/index.html  Developer is issuing the same error as above. Does it work for you? The iframe is also on Dropbox.com, which means I should be able to access it, right?

Comment: You're right, I don't know why, but it doesn't work. I have no other solution. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I found that Dropbox has a script that deters itself from being presented in iframes.